# IIS 7.5 cant access pages (Other than Default Page) without 404 but works in VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7

I'm getting a confusing error and I have googled and googled and gotten no where so wondered if you guys and gals maybe able to help.

Problem:
I have IIS 7.5 running with a published (via VS2015) website sat in C:/DevAspSite/ however only the default page works, so if I go to my website which is running on http://10.208.36.26:3000 it works as it defaults to the set page (vb.aspx) howevr if I do the same and go to http://10.208.36.26:3000/vb.aspx I get a generic 404 error provided by IIS

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This is the same with any .aspx file I have in their default.aspx etc etc, I have another site working on the same IIS using the same application pool etc so dont think its IIS itself.

I have looked at the IIS logs but cant make heads of tails of them

Log:

```
    #Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-03-09 13:35:28
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-03-09 13:35:28 10.208.38.8 GET / - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 2495
2016-03-09 13:35:39 10.208.38.8 GET /Map1.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 301 0 0 31
2016-03-09 13:35:39 10.208.38.8 GET /Map1 - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
2016-03-09 13:36:02 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/Map1.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 301 0 0 12728
2016-03-09 13:36:02 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/Map1 - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
2016-03-09 13:36:10 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 301 0 0 31
2016-03-09 13:36:10 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 202
2016-03-09 13:36:18 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+CMDTDFJS;+InfoPath.3) 404 0 2 15
2016-03-09 13:36:22 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+CMDTDFJS;+InfoPath.3) 301 0 0 15
2016-03-09 13:36:22 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+CMDTDFJS;+InfoPath.3) 404 0 2 15
2016-03-09 13:36:42 10.208.38.8 GET /vb.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+CMDTDFJS;+InfoPath.3) 301 0 0 15
2016-03-09 13:36:42 10.208.38.8 GET /vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+CMDTDFJS;+InfoPath.3) 404 0 2 0
2016-03-09 13:38:42 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb. - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 0 265
2016-03-09 13:38:46 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb.aspx. - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 0 233
2016-03-09 13:38:50 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
2016-03-09 13:41:01 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 233
2016-03-09 13:41:05 10.208.38.8 GET /Maps/vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
2016-03-09 13:41:09 10.208.38.8 GET /vb.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 301 0 0 1341
2016-03-09 13:41:09 10.208.38.8 GET /vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
2016-03-09 13:41:12 10.208.38.8 GET / - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 1294
2016-03-09 13:42:19 10.208.38.8 GET / - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 302 0 0 233
2016-03-09 13:42:29 10.208.38.8 GET / - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 302 0 0 218
2016-03-09 13:42:41 10.208.38.8 GET / - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 200 0 64 1793
2016-03-09 13:42:41 10.208.38.8 GET / - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 1263
2016-03-09 13:46:00 10.208.38.8 GET /vb - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
2016-03-09 13:46:24 10.208.38.8 GET /default.aspx - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 301 0 0 1419
2016-03-09 13:46:24 10.208.38.8 GET /default - 3000 - 10.208.36.26 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 218
```

Not sure if this helps, but currently forcing VS2015 to use VB.NET language which as far as I'm aware MS dropped VB.NET for c# only in the release of VS2015 so not sure as the other working site was made / designed in VS2010.

Any help would be great.
Regards
JB

Comment: have you installed all necessary IIS/.NET Framework modules from the "Turn Windows features on or off" section of Programs and Features in the control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Web Platform Installer and run it;

Search for asp.net registration and mark it to install;

Search for Recommended IIS settings and mark it to install;

Apply the changes;